# Click sound before aircon compressor engaged

Tags: honda, noise, ac

I have a Honda HR-V that I recently purchased. I noticed that there is an audible click sound in the cabin when I turned on my A/C.

Now, I have sent it back to dealership to fix this (it is under warranty) but unfortunately after several workshop visits, they were not able to fully solve the problem. I am here seeking advice if anyone has an idea.

First, it is not the blend door actuator and second the dealership seems to determine that the click sound comes from the engine bay. They did mentioned that one of the A/C hose is making the sound very loudly.

The click sound only happens when the A/C is turned on.

Initially, this click sound was audible after the A/C was turned on for a minute. It would be like "click, click" every 5-10s. The dealership had replaced one of the A/C (believe it's the suction line), and this reduced the frequency to every cycle before the A/C compressor is engaged.

FYI, the dealership had replaced a new compressor and also replaced a relay in the relay box but the issue persisted.

The behavioural now is that this clicking sound is audible most of the time, and you can hear it before the A/C compressor engages. Sometime, the click sound will be audible together with the A/C compressor engages click sound, sometime it will be 2-4seconds before the A/C compressor engages.

Lastly, I can definitely hear these click sounds when I turn off my A/C, there will be several click before it dies down.

The click sound can also either be loud, or soft. There is no consistency.

My gut feeling is that it comes from the A/C hose vibration as when they replaced one of the A/C hose, the frequency reduced significantly to just before the A/C compressor engages.

What do you guys think? TIA.

Answer (score 0):

That's probably just the clutch for the ac compressor activating. The ac compressor uses an electromagnet to pull on a steel plate to engage the clutch with the serpentine belt while it's being used and disengages it to allow it to spin freely when not in use and is usually unnoticed with the radio or something else usually grabbing your attention but since you're now listening for the sound it becomes easy to hear. If you want to check if the compressor is working properly without any tools for peace of mind turn on the ac and let ot run for a bit at idle while parked somewhere safe then pop the hood locate the vompressors location on the drive belt and you should see two connected hoses on it carefully touch each hose and get a sense of its twmperature if working properly there should be a significant difference with one hose being hotter than ambient and the other significantly cooler than ambient. Also the front pulley should be spinning at the speed of the moving belt. If they feel like they are the same temperature or the pulley isn't spinning you know there's an issue with either the compressor or the clutch. Hope this helps. Also careful not to touch any moving parts or have loose clothing or jewelry getting stuck in said moving parts good luck

Comment: Hi. The AC clutch clicking should not be the case as the sound of the click sound is different from this clicking sound that happens before the compressor gets engaged.  I can hear and differentiate the compressor engage clicking sound from this very distinctly in the cabin. I did use another HR-V of same build and model and there is no such clicking sound.